# Get text value from dynamically creating text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol, nested-controls

Given multiple dynamically created textboxes, I want to get the text filled by the user.
I used a Panel and the creation works. The control for the textbox is not found.

ASPX

```
<div>
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
<div>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Adauga autor" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Create Textboxes

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
    rowCount++;
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxA = new TextBox();
        Label lblA = new Label();

        TxtBoxA.ID = "TextBoxA" + i.ToString();
        lblA.ID = "LabelA" + i.ToString();
        lblA.Text = "Label" + i.ToString() + ": ";

        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblA);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxA);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
```

Get Text

```
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    string item = "TextBoxA" + i.ToString();
    Control foundControl = FindControl(item, Page.Controls);
    TextBox TB = (TextBox)foundControl;
    string txt = TB.Text;
}
```

+

```
public static Control FindControl(string controlId, ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        if (control.ID == controlId)
            return control;

        if (control.HasControls())
        {
            Control nestedControl = FindControl(controlId, control.Controls);

            if (nestedControl != null)
                return nestedControl;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Textbox Control is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is _"Get Text"_ located? You have to recreate all controls in `Page_Load` at the latest. `Button1_Click` is later.

Comment: string txt = TB.Text; But why Page_Load? I need the text only after input at Button1_Click.

Comment: You have to re-create all dynamically created controls in `Page_init` or `Page_Load`, later (like the event-handler) is _too_ late for `ViewState` etc. Also, your recursive `FindControl` is unnecessary. Use the "normal" `FindControl` on the control's `NamingContainer`. Since you don't use controls which implement `INamingContainer`(like `GridView)` you can simply use `Page.FindControl(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate all controls in `Page_Load`  at the latest. `Button1_Click` is too late. So recreate `Session["clicks"]` in `Page_Init`/`Page_Load` and create the single new control in the `Button-Click`-handler.

Some code:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RecreateControls();
}

 private void RecreateControls()
 {
     int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
     CreateControls(rowCount);
 }

 private void AddControl()
 {
     int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
     CreateControls(1);
     Session["clicks"] = rowCount++;
 }

 private void CreateControls(int count)
 {
     for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     {
         TextBox TxtBoxA = new TextBox();
         Label lblA = new Label();

         TxtBoxA.ID = "TextBoxA" + i.ToString();
         lblA.ID = "LabelA" + i.ToString();
         lblA.Text = "Label" + i.ToString() + ": ";

         Panel1.Controls.Add(lblA);
         Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxA);
         Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
     }
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     AddControl();
 }
```